# Unable to get the rich buttons to work on dialogflow. It returns Empty Response

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

So I have been trying to start off with creating chatbots on dialogflow. The issue I am running into is that my chatbot is meant to give users a bunch of options to select from and to take the conversation further from there. In order to implement that, I've used a suggestion chip I've included the JSON file that I am using. However, when testing, the bot detects the right intent but returns an empty response. I've included the code in case that helps.

```
    {
      "richContent": [
       [
        {
          "options": [
            {
              "text": "Chip 1",
              "image": {
                 "src": {
                    "rawUrl": "https://example.com/images/logo.png"
                         }
                        },
              "link": "https://example.com"
            },
        {
        "link": "https://example.com",
        "text": "Chip 2",
        "image": {
          "src": {
            "rawUrl": "https://example.com/images/logo.png"
                 }
                }
              }
            ],
            "type": "chips"
            }
          ]
         ]
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing it in the console, you definitely won't get any response, since there is some issue with the way console works. Use dialogflow messenger to test it. Anyways in the actual production you won't be using simulator to test it. Dialogflow console is a simulator which has some capability restrictions but it will work when you use the messenger.